# Prefill the JQuery multiselect tool

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I want to fill this jQuery object with data that is being pulled from the database. Once I have this data, how can I get it to populate the field where it shows what has been selected (essentially giving the users an option to delete existing conditions)

http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

That's the example site and the specific container I'm using is called "Multiple Select"

```
    $(".chosen-select").chosen({
                    no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!",
                    width: "95%"
                });
```

Comment: @MamaWalter I'm not sure what to try really, this is a new JQuery object I'm experimenting with. 

I've just initialized and populated the original select I've made that edit above.

Comment: not sure to understand, you want to add `options` to the `select` when the page load or later (ajax call success) ? could you show your `PHP` and the `HTML` of what you want ?

Comment: There is a field that populates in the Multiple Select above the drop down. Before the user does anything I'm trying to load data into that field which populates on the select of an item from the dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/xDm2n/1/

```
$('#chosen-select').chosen();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/echo/json/',
    data: {
        json: JSON.stringify({
            options: ['American Black Bear',
                'Asiatic Black Bear',
                'Brown Bear',
                'Giant Panda',
                'Sloth Bear',
                'Sun Bear',
                'Polar Bear',
                'Spectacled Bear'],
            selected: ['Brown Bear', 'Sun Bear']
        }),
        delay: 0
    }
}).done(function (response) {
    var a, element;
    for (i = 0; i < response.options.length; i++) {
        a = response.selected.indexOf(response.options[i]);
        element = $("<option/>").text(response.options[i]);
        if (a >= 0) element.attr('selected', 'selected');
        element.appendTo($("#chosen-select"));
    };
    $("#chosen-select").trigger("chosen:updated");
});
```

You can fill your select element as you would normally, set the items you want selected, and then trigger the update event ("chosen:updated")

Comment: It was actually an even easier than this, when populating the option drop down for this tool just add a select for the one's that already exist. The JQuery function takes care of the rest of the pre-populating! 

This was the closest answer to that.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have some options to be already selected when the page load just add `selected="selected"` for the values return from the database.

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/shEX5/2/)

If you get your database values with an `ajax call` you will have to trigger a change event: `$("#form_field").trigger("chosen:updated");`